# Using PHP Symlink for Drupal Multisite

Tags: drupal, symlink

Sorry if the question is a bit vague. Here is my situation.

I have Drupal installed in a sub folder at www.example.com/testing. Within this, I want another sub folder for a mobile version of the main Drupal installation (www.example.com/testing/mobile).

Therefore, the mobile site needs to share the database, codebase, modules, themes etc of the main Drupal installation. I believe I need to create a folder within the 'sites' folder called 'mobile' which includes a copy of the settings.php file and a directory called 'files'.

I am then stuck as to what else I need to do to complete the set up of the mobile installation. I have seen some articles about using symlinks but it's going over my head at the moment!

Any help, advice or links would be appreciated! Also, I do not have access to shell so cannot perform any command line programming on the server.

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Themekey module to load a specific theme when a user on a mobile device visits the website. That would not require duplicating code or files, and all you have to do is supply the theme to it, and it will do the rest.

http://drupal.org/project/themekey

As for symlinks, I like to use them when I upgrade code.

Here is an example:

```
mkdir share/1.0
ln -s share/1.0 public_html (or htdocs, whatever the server is set as)
```

That would create a symlink pointing your virtual host webroot at the new directory. So, when you update the code and test it, you create a new folder called 1.1 for the new version of code, and update the symlink. But, symlinks are not needed in this case for simply having a mobile version of the website.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'd not come across ThemKey before but it does look useful.